# Android app stuck on black screen

Tags: android

logcat:

```
04-26 16:28:20.623 6848-6848/com.example.irit.myapp D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-26 16:28:20.623 6848-6848/com.example.irit.myapp E/MotionRecognitionManager: mSContextService = android.hardware.scontext.ISContextService$Stub$Proxy@c651538
04-26 16:28:20.623 6848-6848/com.example.irit.myapp E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@4d14911
04-26 16:28:20.623 6848-6848/com.example.irit.myapp E/MotionRecognitionManager: motionService = com.samsung.android.motion.IMotionRecognitionService$Stub$Proxy@4d14911
```

I don't know if this is an error, but sometimes, when i want load my list view dynamically, my app is just stuck, and the screen become black.
this happen something like 1/10 times

my code which is run :
in my onClickListener:

```
Intent intentHisto = new Intent(EnvoiMailActivity.this, HistoriqueActivity.class);
EnvoiMailActivity.this.startActivity(intentHisto);
```

in my activity :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    setContentView(R.layout.historique);
    this.mGoogleAccount = GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_USED;
    this.mMessageControlleur = new MessageControlleur(this);

    if (Conf.MESSAGE_HISTORIQUE == null){
        try {
            listMessage = mMessageControlleur.GetMessageSameRecipient(mGoogleAccount.getmGmail(), mGoogleAccount.getmCredential().getSelectedAccountName(), Conf.EMAIL_DU_SERVICE);
            Conf.MESSAGE_HISTORIQUE = listMessage;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else{
        listMessage = Conf.MESSAGE_HISTORIQUE;
    }
    createTitle();
    //this.mHistoriquePagerAdapter = new HistoriquePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    //this.mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    //this.mViewPager.setAdapter(mHistoriquePagerAdapter);
    try {
        this.adapter = new MyArrayAdapterMail(this, R.layout.mail_visualise, mMessageControlleur.messageToMimeMesssage(listMessage));
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    this.mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mListView.setAdapter(this.adapter);


}
```

I think my app is stuck befor the first if in my onCreate, because when nothing is wrong, i got another logcat : `GetMessageSameRecipient()` return

Comment: use `startActivity(intentHisto);` enough. The logcat you provided not really an error I think.

Comment: @JohnJoe its logged as Error as you can see E/Motionrecognition..... the E is the indicator for error

Comment: Yes it's an error, but i really don't know from where it come from